# Security Exception with SelectPdf .net

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have unloaded the version free Community Edition from

http://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/demo/

Because I wanted to use the example that turned a page html into pdf.
In visual studio I have succeeded in using the file asp.net but when I put it online I receive this error:

Security Exception
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

I have loaded the files on three different servers.
Azure, Aruba and Godaddy, but do I always receive the same error, as I can resolve?

http://pdf.cyberkings.fr/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx

http://www.numero-telefono.it/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx

Thanks

Comment: I have looked for online some information.  And I have added this line     [assembly: System.Security.AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers ()] in the file AssemblyInfo.cs

The error is now changed Now me by this error.
Conversion failure. Could not find 'Select.Html.dep'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 


This makes me think that it doesn't find some files But me I have loaded the whole project what I don't understand indeed it is because the place works everything and online no.
Do you have some suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Conversion failure. Could not find 'Select.Html.dep'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request

When installing `Select.HtmlToPdf` from NuGET, the installation copies the dependancy file `Select.Html.dep` to the bin. When you build, a copy gets placed in the /bin beside Select.HtmlToPdf.dll.

However, when deploying your application, the dependency file does not get copied automatically.

**You need to copy `Select.Html.dep` manually.**

See the *SelectPdf Html To Pdf Converter for .NET* [deployment documentation.](http://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/Deployment.htm)

Comment: In my case, I updated the nuget to the latest version and that `Select.Html.dep` file was in the root of my project. It started working once I manually DELETED that from the project root. After that, rebuilt the solution and it worked.. weird, I guess the newer versions perhaps fixed the underlying issue and now the included file was just a leftover from an older version and it was causing some conflict.